# how do I set the right side container to scroll in it's own place

Tags: html, css

So here's the link to [my site](http://directory.shopious.com). I wanted the right container to scroll in place. How can I do this? I tried adding `position: fixed` to the right column but then that destroys the layout. Right now the overflow always scrolls all the way to the top.. Basically I wanted `insta-shop-grid` to scroll inside that container itself.

Comment: Don't understand your question exactly. You could add a Z-index to your banner `div` if you want to avoid the banner being overrun with text...

Comment: I don't want to add the z-index of the banner to 1 as it would still look weird. I wanted the 'SHOP DIRECTORY' to stay in place and the scroller to be inside insta-shop-grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited it as inline style

see if it works. add them to a class.

```
<div class="directory-container container" style="
max-height: 400px;
z-index: 1111111;
overflow: scroll;width: 100%;
margin-top: 361px;

">
```

and add `<body style="overflow:none">`

But website really needs some responsive designing. i used 400px and 360 for margin as padding was already there. :) still I hope this will work

Comment: but for having the div to scroll you will have to remove the scroll of the parent. You cannot just drag the only body scroller down

Answer (score 1):

Adding `z-index: -1` to the main content, prevents it from scrolling above the banner.

See simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbmHB/1/).

*Update:*

Stealing from @Anobik, I modified my example, removed the `z-index` and added a `fixed` wrapper around the main content

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">Banner</div>
<div class="nav">Navigation</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Main content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 125px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbmHB/2/)